# osql can not find IP address, tsql works on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, odbc, freetds

I am having ODBC problems on Ubuntu (12.10). The weirdest part about it - I set all of this up a year ago and haven't had any trouble with it until recently.

I am trying to connect to a MS SQL Server using FreeTDS / ODBC. I primarily use sqsh to talk to the server, but when I need to do anything analytical, I pull the data into R using RODBC. Yesterday, when I tried to do this, it failed.

I can connect to the database using sqsh / tsql. This makes me think FreeTDS is still set up correctly. The problem seems to be on the ODBC side. So, I pulled out osql and I get the strangest error.

```
checking shared odbc libraries linked to isql for default directories...
strings: '': No such file
        trying /tmp/sql ... no
        trying /tmp/sql ... no
        trying /etc ... OK
checking odbc.ini files
        reading /home/andy/.odbc.ini
[CANS] found in /home/andy/.odbc.ini
found this section:
        [CANS]
        Description                     = FreeTDS
        Driver                      = FreeTDS
        Servername                      = Portland
        Database                        = CANS
        UID                             = NotRelevant
        PWD                             = NotRelevant
        Port                        = 1433

looking for driver for DSN [CANS] in /home/andy/.odbc.ini
  found driver line: "  Driver                      = FreeTDS"
  driver "FreeTDS" found for [CANS] in .odbc.ini
found driver named "FreeTDS"
"FreeTDS" is not an executable file
looking for entry named [FreeTDS] in /etc/odbcinst.ini
  found driver line: "  Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so"
  found driver /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so for [FreeTDS] in 
        odbcinst.ini
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so is an executable file
    Using ODBC-Combined strategy
DSN [CANS] has servername "Portland" (from /home/andy/.odbc.ini)
cannot read "/home/andy/.freetds.conf"
/etc/freetds/freetds.conf is a readable file
looking for [Portland] in /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
found this section:
    [Portland]
        host           = 63.***.**.***
        port           = 1433
        tds version    = 8.0
        client charset = UTF-8
looking up hostname for ip address 63.***.**.***
osql: no IP address found for "host145.actwd.net"
```

I don't understand why osql is trying to resolve an IP address when it has it already. This server has quite a bit of IP blocking going on to help protect it and you can only access it from a set of white-listed IP addresses. You can't do a DNS lookup on the address. I'm at the office so my IP address is fine and furthermore, I can connect using tsql, so this part shouldn't be a problem, but this looks like the failure point.

Thoughts?

One other note, actwd.net is our host. So, this isn't totally zany, I just don't know why it doesn't use the IP address I'm handing it.

Comment: `osql` does: `HOST=$(host ${HOST} | awk '/domain/ {print $5}' | sed 's/\.$//')` so if anything goes wrong with that, it will tell you "no DNS hostname". In my case, the `host` command wasn't installed.

Answer (score 1):

Today's lesson - Before posting something onto Stack Overflow - I should have noticed that somehow my port numbers got changed from 1433 to 1044. No idea how  I managed to do that, but that was the problem.

SQL Server expects a connection on port 1433. Not 1044. There are days I really don't like computers . . . .

Answer (score 0):

I received an IP address error because my odbc.ini was specifying the "Server" setting as opposed to the "Servername" setting.  The former is the actual server, the latter is an entry in freetds.conf.